# Why XMLHttpRequest only working for Twitter json?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

PhoneGap will print out the json from twitter below. However when I use any other url for my ajax.open it just shows a blank screen.
Apologies for messy code layout

```
 <pre>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
         function appReady(){

         }
         document.addEventListener("deviceready", appReady, false);
         var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();   
         ajax.open("GET","http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bacon",true);

         ajax.send();

         ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
         if(ajax.readyState==4 && (ajax.status==200))
         {
           document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
         }
       }
       </script>
      Hello
 <div id="main">
 </pre>
```

Using eclipse I created a Webserver and started coding these requests from my localhost and using the code below, minus the phonegap.js in the script tag and it worked fine for calling html from /Test2.html". I removed the "phonegap.js" because on my local machine its not using phonegap, I did replace it with "Test.js", which just contains this code, which I obtained from W3school documentation on XMLHttpRequest:

When I try to get my emulator to call /Test2.html it shows a blank screen.Also from my own server I am unable to call twitter json, I expect this due to cross domain protection is back on since im not working with phonegap.

Can anyone tell me why I am unable to view Test2 and other urls using this code on my Emulator.
also does anyone know of any other online jsons available, I tried a google and yahoo ones but they also dont seem to work on either.

```
function handler() {
 if(this.readyState == this.DONE) {
if(this.status == 200 && this.responseXML != null && this.responseXML.getElementById('test').textContent) 
{
  // success!
  processData(this.responseXML.getElementById('test').textContent);
  return;
}
// something went wrong
processData(null);
}
}
```

Comment: What "other URL" are you using that is getting a blank? For any URL you use, you should be able to just put that URL into your browser and see what it's going to return. If it's returning blank, it will return blank to the AJAX call.

Comment: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json was the other json I was trying to connect to. When I put it into my browser I can see the json but It will not output to my screenon the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need an "API Key" to access other JSON streams.  Twitter does not require such a key.

Comment: How do I tell if a particular json needs a key, for example: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json

Comment: Yup, you were right it was an access issue, I tested it out on a few other webpages, some that required access and other that didnt. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That is why Twitter tends to be a "de facto" example API for programming platforms to create their JASON "Hello World" examples & tutorils: No API Key needed, with lots of fresh & useful data!